# How to say that my current line of work coincides with my education

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

How is it possible to say that my current line of work coincides with my education? For example, I have a BS degree in Chemistry and work as a chemist (not as a salesperson or a programmer). Perhaps there is some idiom or common short expression.

In Russian, there is an expression that could be literally translated "work by speciality". I don't think that it's a nice expression in English.

Comment: I would say that I work in my profession.

Comment: "I work in my field of study." Rather literal (not idiomatic), but concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word ***trained*** used in adjective sense (applied to a *profession*) is typically used to mean that the person in question also had formal education in that field, as in *trained chemist*.

> I am a ***trained*** chemist.

To make it more explicit (although elaborate), you can also say:

> I am a chemist (both) by profession and training.

Macmillan:

> **[trained](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trained)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> someone who is trained for a profession or job has all the necessary
>   skills and qualifications
>
> There’s a shortage of trained language teachers.
>   A team of trained
>   volunteers will be available to help.

Answer (score 2):

"I have a BS in Chemistry and I work in field"
This is a concise way of saying what you wish, but a little more may be better:
"I have a BS in Chemistry and I work in field as a chemist".
Better still would be to state, in addition, in what area of chemistry you work.
"I have a BS in Chemistry and I work in field as an organic chemist".

Answer (score 1):

First word that came into my mind was *relevance*, followed by *coherence*, but I see that a lot of studies talk about **"occupation-education matching"**.
Give it a search (as it is, within quotation marks) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Just giving examples of your current work will tell them you are currently working as a Chemist. Even if it is in another section, they will make the connection, and figure out you are currently working in the same field you have your education in. If they have a question about it, they will look over what you have written to see your work and education are the same. They shouldn't mistake you for anything other than what you claim to be.